# Angular Dynamic Route Declaration for Multiple Versions of Pages

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 11 website and have created a mechanism where I can have different versions of the same page and control which page is used via app settings. The goal is for the url to be the same no matter which version of the page is being used. I have implemented a way to achieve this, with the exception of one use case. I will outline my solution, than the problem with it which I need to solve.

To accomplish this, I have a module (to be lazy loaded) which represents the actual/true route for the page. That module itself is only responsible for determining which version of the page to use, then it will route to that version, but mark as "skipNavigationChange" so the url appears to be the same. Each version of the page will have its own module and will be routed to depending upon that invisible route. This is done by a component which otherwise is empty.

This is working, with the exception of query params. When I update the route to have query params, it also re-adds the internal route to the url, which I don't want. For example: "/page" will become "/page/version-name?param=true" when I append the query param.

There are two ways I can think to approach it but am not sure how to proceed for either:

- Find a way to keep that "version-name" part of the path hidden when updating query params.
- Find a way to dynamically point a route to the appropriate version based on app setting. Note: the app setting is retrieved via observable and is not immediately available upon startup.

Please advise and point to any references if applicable.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. If it were me I would try pointing the route to a 'layout' component that is responsible for determining which version to display. That also easily solves the setting being retrieved via observable as the wrapping component could manage it's own state and display a loading indicator. I don't really think there is a 'right' way, but just my opinion and how I would go about it.

Comment: That is the current approach I am taking now, that component reads the app setting and routes with "skipLocationChange" accordingly. However, when I try to update query params, that version name / route appears in the url, which is undesired.

Comment: /store/item ===> store/item/version-name-route?item=true